# a codeigniters helper function in a controllers function is not executing

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is a call to a controllers function :

```
function downloadFile(fn,con)
        {
            var loadUrl = "/Fast-Docs/index.php/Docs/downloadFile";
                alert('hi');
        $.post(  
            loadUrl,  
            {content: con, filename: fn});  
        }
```

controllers function :

```
public function downloadFile()
{
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $content=$this->input->post('content');
    $fn=$this->input->post('filename');
    return force_download($fn,$content);
}
```

but file is not downloading.

i know the reason why its not working but i dnt know how to fix it. so whats the solution. you need some more info , feel free to ask.

Comment: show the code for `force_download()`

Comment: its a helper function provided by codeigniter

Comment: A function? Or a method? If the framework provides it, wouldn't you call it with $this->force_download($fn, $content);

Comment: i tried it, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand what you are trying to do. Anyway, there is a fundamental problem in your code.

You are doing an ajax request to the `"/Fast-Docs/index.php/Docs/downloadFile"` URL, but you are ignoring the response.

My suggestion is: forget about ajax and use a simple link.

```
<a href="/Fast-Docs/index.php/Docs/downloadFile/myfile.png">Download file</a>
```

Then in the controller:

```
public function downloadFile($filename)
{
    //Validate file name
    if($filename != 'validFileName') die('Invalid file name');

    //Set headers
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $content = file_get_contents('/images/' . $filename);
    force_download($filename, $content);
}
```

If for some reason you can't use a link, you can redirect to the download page (by setting `window.location`).

If you really need to use ajax, give a look at [this](http://kdelchev.com/2012/07/send-file-download-ajax/).